# how to submit Form with AJAX Using enctype="multipart/form-data"?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

how to submit Form with AJAX Using enctype="multipart/form-data"?

Comment: You can use XMLHttpRequest method. 
Look this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974684/how-to-send-formdata-objects-with-ajax-requests-in-jquery

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Short answer: you don't. You cannot upload files via AJAX.

The usual workaround is to set the target of your form to a hidden `iframe` and submit the form there, using a normal, non-AJAXy POST, to achieve the desired effect:

```
<form target="hiddenIframe" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    ...
</form>
<iframe name="hiddenIframe" id="hiddenIframe" style="display: none;" />
```

There's a [jQuery plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/iframe-post-form) that uses this technique.

#### Edited to add:

[XMLHttpRequest level 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest2/) added support for uploading files via AJAX, and its browser support is now good and growing. Here's a [browser support overview](http://caniuse.com/#feat=xhr2).

Comment: This information is out of date, uploading files via AJAX IS possible now, and quite easy. Take a look at XHR2. A good post is here at HTML5Rocks: http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/04/Processing-XHR2-file-uploads-in-PHP

Comment: Link for the jQuery plugin is now void. I'm trying to fix a solution for old browsers, so that would come in handy (if you can find it again) :)

Answer (score -1):

### Here's a way that works even with IE8 and above:

Use malsup's [jquery form plugin](https://github.com/malsup/form/), which will take care of both XHR as well as the hidden iframe that IE needs for ajax upload.

Code snippet here:

```
<form id="formid" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8">
.
.
.
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            var options = { 
                cache:'false',   //IE FIX
                data: $('#formid').serialize(),
                dataType: 'json',
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function(data) 
                {
                    //success action
                },
                error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
                {
                    //error action
                }
            }; 
            $('#formid').ajaxForm(options); 
        });
</script>
```