# How to send FormData objects with Ajax-requests in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, multipartform-data

The [XMLHttpRequest Level 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest2/) standard (still a working draft) defines the `FormData` interface. This interface enables appending `File` objects to XHR-requests (Ajax-requests).

Btw, this is a new feature - in the past, the "hidden-iframe-trick" was used (read about that in [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6718664/is-it-possible-to-peform-an-asynchronous-cross-domain-file-upload/6963843)).

This is how it works (example):

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
    fd = new FormData();

fd.append( 'file', input.files[0] );
xhr.open( 'POST', 'http://example.com/script.php', true );
xhr.onreadystatechange = handler;
xhr.send( fd );
```

where `input` is a `<input type="file">` field, and `handler` is the success-handler for the Ajax-request.

This works beautifully in all browsers (again, except IE).

Now, I would like to make this functionality work with jQuery. I tried this:

```
var fd = new FormData();    
fd.append( 'file', input.files[0] );

$.post( 'http://example.com/script.php', fd, handler );
```

Unfortunately, that won't work (an "Illegal invocation" error is thrown - [screenshot is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyNel.png)). I assume jQuery expects a simple key-value object representing form-field-names / values, and the `FormData` instance that I'm passing in is apparently incompatible.

Now, since it is possible to pass a `FormData` instance into `xhr.send()`, I hope that it is also possible to make it work with jQuery.

---

**Update:**

I've created a "feature ticket" over at jQuery's Bug Tracker. It's here: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9995

I was suggested to use an "Ajax prefilter"...

---

**Update:**

First, let me give a demo demonstrating what behavior I would like to achieve.

HTML:

```
<form>
    <input type="file" id="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
$( 'form' ).submit(function ( e ) {
    var data, xhr;

    data = new FormData();
    data.append( 'file', $( '#file' )[0].files[0] );

    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open( 'POST', 'http://hacheck.tel.fer.hr/xml.pl', true );
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function ( response ) {};
    xhr.send( data );

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

The above code results in this HTTP-request:

[image: multipartformdata]

**This is what I need** - I want that "multipart/form-data" content-type!

---

The proposed solution would be like so:

```
$( 'form' ).submit(function ( e ) {
    var data;

    data = new FormData();
    data.append( 'file', $( '#file' )[0].files[0] );

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://hacheck.tel.fer.hr/xml.pl',
        data: data,
        processData: false,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function ( data ) {
            alert( data );
        }
    });

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

However, this results in:

[image: wrongcontenttype]

As you can see, the content type is wrong...

Comment: @zaf Setting `processData:false` is a step in the right direction (see pradeek's proposed solution). Now if I could manually set the "Content-Type" HTTP-request header... See my updated question for details.

Comment: jQuery 4.0.0-beta now officially supports binary data. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77960233/8583692).

Answer (score 1019, accepted):

I believe you could do it like this :

```js
var fd = new FormData();    
fd.append( 'file', input.files[0] );

$.ajax({
  url: 'http://example.com/script.php',
  data: fd,
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  type: 'POST',
  success: function(data){
    alert(data);
  }
});
```

Notes:

- Setting `processData` to `false` lets you prevent jQuery from automatically transforming the data into a query string. See [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for more info.
- Setting the `contentType` to `false` is imperative, since otherwise jQuery [will set it incorrectly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5976031/33080).

Comment: Unfortunately, this results in the wrong "Content-Type" HTTP-request header being set. See my question for detailed explanation what I want to achieve and why your current solution doesn't satisfy. Maybe I can set the Content-Type manually?

Comment: Yes,I believe you could manually set the contentType to 'multipart/form-data' by adding a key-value pair in $.ajax argument.

Comment: Hi @pradeek, we tried this solution here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10215425/upload-photo-with-facebook-graph-api-and-javascript-convert-canvas-image-to-mul), but it wasn't clear how to pass the image data in the body of the POST request. Any clues? Thanks!

Comment: @Crashalot Can you be clear as to what you are trying to do? This question involves uploading a file whereas the one you've linked to involves sending canvas data as an image to the server.

Comment: @pradeek, sorry for the confusion. we're trying to send canvas data as an image to the server as multipart/form-data. the goal is to upload a photo directly to facebook, but facebook expects the image data, as multipart/form-data, in the body of a POST request.

Comment: @pradeek : what is 'input' here js object

Comment: Not working with jquery 1.7.2, `/myurl?[object%20FormData]` :(

Comment: Tested in Firefox, and Chrome. This is the solution.

Comment: Setting processData and contentType to false fixed the issue for me. Thank you, that was unpleasant.

Comment: @SalmanPK if you're getting that url, you are sending it as a GET, this will only work as a POST

Comment: with the example provided, IE will send full path of the input file while Chrome and Firefox will send just the filename. To get just the filename you need to use this line: fd.append('file', input.files[0], input.files[0].name);

Comment: alternatively, you could convert FromData to a plain object, expected "natively" by jQuery: `$.ajax({ ..., data: Object.fromEntries(fd.entries()) ...})`

Comment: fixed it with contentType: false, i had a typo on it, it was driving me crazy! thanks!

Answer (score 34):

You can send the FormData object in ajax request using the following code,

```
$("form#formElement").submit(function(){
    var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
});
```

This is very similar to the accepted answer but an actual answer to the question topic. This will submit the form elements automatically in the FormData and you don't need to manually append the data to FormData variable.

The ajax method looks like this,

```
$("form#formElement").submit(function(){
    var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
    //append some non-form data also
    formData.append('other_data',$("#someInputData").val());
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: postDataUrl,
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
           //process data
        },
        error: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
           //process error msg
        },
});
```

You can also manually pass the form element inside the FormData object as a parameter like this

```
var formElem = $("#formId");
var formdata = new FormData(formElem[0]);
```

Hope it helps. ;)

Comment: Isn't `$(this)[0]` the same as `this` ?

Comment: Why $(this) returns an array?

Comment: @halbano `$(this)` returns not array, but jQuery collection object which can be iterated over just like array. `form[0]` does almost exactly the same as `form.first()`, which just returns the first, real HTML element.

Answer (score 31):

There are a few yet to be mentioned techniques available for you. Start with setting the contentType property in your ajax params.

Building on pradeek's example:

```
$('form').submit(function (e) {
    var data;

    data = new FormData();
    data.append('file', $('#file')[0].files[0]);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://hacheck.tel.fer.hr/xml.pl',
        data: data,
        processData: false,
        type: 'POST',

        // This will override the content type header, 
        // regardless of whether content is actually sent.
        // Defaults to 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        contentType: 'multipart/form-data', 

        //Before 1.5.1 you had to do this:
        beforeSend: function (x) {
            if (x && x.overrideMimeType) {
                x.overrideMimeType("multipart/form-data");
            }
        },
        // Now you should be able to do this:
        mimeType: 'multipart/form-data',    //Property added in 1.5.1

        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

In some cases when forcing jQuery ajax to do non-expected things, the `beforeSend` event is a great place to do it. For a while people were using `beforeSend` to override the mimeType before that was added into jQuery in 1.5.1. You should be able to modify just about anything on the jqXHR object in the before send event.

Comment: There is a problem with this: [the spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html) requires that a multipart content-type includes the boundary parameter (specifically, it’s stated as a *required* parameter).

Comment: @romkyns I was coding this from the top of my head. If you have some experience/knowledge that I don't, please go ahead and edit the answer! Now that you mentioned it, a quick search turned up this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5933949/how-to-send-multipart-form-data-form-content-by-ajax-no-jquery which should get you going in the right direction. (You could take from that example and incorporate it into the above jQuery if you are into that.)

Comment: Actually the currently accepted answer (that I edited to add a crucial fix) does the right thing, at last. This was tricky :)

Comment: I had high hopes for this solution, but my $_FILES is still NULL...

Answer (score 7):

I do it like this and it's work for me, I hope this will help :)

```
   <div id="data">
        <form>
            <input type="file" name="userfile" id="userfile" size="20" />
            <br /><br />
            <input type="button" id="upload" value="upload" />
        </form>
    </div>
  <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#upload').click(function(){

                    console.log('upload button clicked!')
                    var fd = new FormData();    
                    fd.append( 'userfile', $('#userfile')[0].files[0]);

                    $.ajax({
                      url: 'upload/do_upload',
                      data: fd,
                      processData: false,
                      contentType: false,
                      type: 'POST',
                      success: function(data){
                        console.log('upload success!')
                        $('#data').empty();
                        $('#data').append(data);

                      }
                    });
                });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: How is this different from the accepted answer?

Comment: fd.append( 'userfile', **$('#userfile')[0]**.files[0]); THIS is the different you need to add the id's for input file to work.

Comment: This one helped me than others..

Answer (score 5):

JavaScript:

```
function submitForm() {
    var data1 = new FormData($('input[name^="file"]'));
    $.each($('input[name^="file"]')[0].files, function(i, file) {
        data1.append(i, file);
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>employee/dashboard2/test2",
        type: "POST",
        data: data1,
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        processData: false, // tell jQuery not to process the data
        contentType: false // tell jQuery not to set contentType
    }).done(function(data) {
        console.log("PHP Output:");
        console.log(data);
    });
    return false;
}
```

PHP:

```
public function upload_file() {
    foreach($_FILES as $key) {
        $name = time().$key['name'];
        $path = 'upload/'.$name;
        @move_uploaded_file($key['tmp_name'], $path);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the $.ajax `beforeSend` event to manipulate the header.

…

```
beforeSend: function(xhr) { 
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
}
```

…

See this link for additional information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536752(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you want to submit files using ajax use "jquery.form.js"
This submits all form elements easily.

Samples
http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#ajaxSubmit

rough view :

```
<form id='AddPhotoForm' method='post' action='../photo/admin_save_photo.php' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showResponseAfterAddPhoto(responseText, statusText)
{ 
    information= responseText;
    callAjaxtolist();
    $("#AddPhotoForm").resetForm();
    $("#photo_msg").html('<div class="album_msg">Photo uploaded Successfully...</div>');        
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.add_new_photo_div').live('click',function(){
            var options = {success:showResponseAfterAddPhoto};  
            $("#AddPhotoForm").ajaxSubmit(options);
        });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of -  `fd.append( 'userfile', $('#userfile')[0].files[0]);`

Use - `fd.append( 'file', $('#userfile')[0].files[0]);`

Comment: If you can explain the difference, I'll give you a cookie.